# Why are 'change db' and 'set option' so high in the MySQL query stats?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

So I was checking the MySQL query statistics in phpMyAdmin last week after restarting the MySQL server and noticed that **change db** calls were accounting for the large majority of the stats at 91%.  In second place were the **set option** calls at around 2%, then followed by all the normal calls (**select**, **insert**, **update**,...).

In my research, most people mentioned that this was because of accessing phpMyAdmin and the way it reads from the database, so I've waited a week without accessing phpMyAdmin and then logged in today.  The stats currently show **change db** calls at 93% with over 257,000 calls per hour and over 12,330,000 since last week!!!  That can't be right, can it?  I searched through the code on the sites on this dedicated server for any calls to **change db**, but found nothing.

Where are these coming from?  Are these calls causing a detrimental load on the server?

[image: MySQL query statistics in phpMyAdmin showing 93% change db calls]

Comment: change db appears to be when use change to the database. so depending upon how you are creating connections in your code. it could be the library, opens connection to the server, then changes over to your database. so if you have code the say opens a connection to the database as part of every page hit, then doesn't issue any queries, that could drive those numbers.  I would compare it against your page hits to see how close they are.

Comment: Interesting thought...I use PHP's mysql_connect() for any connections on that server, and make sure to mysql_close() after each one is finished.  Could that still force the 'change db' calls each time mysql_connect() runs?  BTW, I'm 100% sure that the 'select' calls should far outweigh the 'change db' calls if this is the case...for each connection, I have an average of about 3-4 select calls run.  Strange indeed.

Comment: normally you do mysql_connect(); mysql_select_db(); the latter is what is probably calling the change_db call (<insert std disclaimer about not using mysql_ functions in php>).  but yes in theory the selects should outweigh  that, which is why I was say look to see if you open a connection on pages that don't ever issue a select (LIke including the call to mysql_connect/select_db in a common include. that gets sourced on every page, regardless of is that page requires sql queries.

Comment: I reviewed most of the code on the server (everything but one Wordpress installation) and saw that mysql_select_db() was always called in context with a query.  The code included mysql_connect() when needed and called mysql_select_db() just before mysql_query() in every context that I saw, whether it was a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE or otherwise.  Knowing this, I still don't think it makes sense that the CHANGE DB calls would far outweigh everything else...shouldn't the CHANGE DB calls should more or less match the total of all of the rest of the db queries (e.g. one CHANGE DB for each query run)?